# How to modify the fundamental postulate once knowing the initial conditions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The strong power and useful of [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) is based on the only fundamental postulate:

> For an isolated system with an exactly known energy and exactly known composition, the system can be found with $\textbf{equal probability}$ in any microstate consistent with that knowledge.

That we can make this axiom relies heavily on we are ignorant of the initial conditions of the system. (Q: Is this right?)

My second question is: Once we know the initial condition for the system, how to modify the fundamental postulate?

Comment: Keep in mind that thermal physics is largely used on large systems. Next, consider the amount of data required to know the position and momentum of one nanomole of ideal gas to, say, IEEE single precision in each measurement. Compare to a very large mass storage facility. Then consider the utter uselessness such crude measurements even if the system could be treated classically. Then consider that QM render all this assumption of determinism moot. There are good reasons for building the subject on a foundation of ignorance of the details: because it works and you *can't* know the details.